# Need to sort array of objects called from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array of objects that I fetch and then display on my page. The order however keeps changing. How do I call them in a fixed order?

```
function chatFetch(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          dataType: "json",
          method: "GET",

          success: function(data){

                $("ul").empty();

                for(var key in data) {
                    for(var i in data[key]){
                      console.log(data[key][i])
                      $(".messages").append("<li>"+data[key][i].text+"</li>");
                    }
                }    

          }
      })
    }
```

This is an example of one of the objects. But you see,

```
Object {
   text: "RoboChat: Johnny 5 alive!", 
   username: "RoboChat", 
   createdAt: "2014-03-19T18:51:28.600Z", 
   updatedAt: "2014-03-19T18:51:28.600Z", 
   objectId: "NKh7VaWY5X"
}
```

But when I fetch the array again, the object looks like this:

```
Object {
   text: "RoboChat: Johnny 5 alive!", 
   username: "RoboChat", 
   createdAt: "2014-03-19T18:52:18.533Z", 
   updatedAt: "2014-03-19T18:52:18.533Z", 
   objectId: "xnRMkxJMX3"
}
```

Ideally, I would like them sorted according to the order they were generated in. Is it possible that they have random key ordering? How do I change that, on my end, not server side.

Comment: How would you like them sorted? Alphabetically? Could you post your array of objects?

Comment: By the iteration method, it all looks like objects, and as pointed out by @A.Wolff there is no order in objects, hence why it's never the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `data` is an actual array use [***sort***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom compare function

```
data.sort(function(dataA,dataB){
   if(dataA.someThing > dataB.someThing){
      return 1;
   } else if(dataA.someThing < dataB.someThing){
      return -1;
   } else {
      return 0;
   }
};
```

Also if `data` is an array do not use the `for in` loop as it will loop over the array properties as well as the elements in the array.

If it is an object then just apply the sort on the `data[key]` element

```
data[key].sort(...)
```

If you do not need any special type of sorting, ie just lexicographic, then just call `sort()` without any arguments.

**EDIT:**

if you are wanting to sort on `createdAt`

```
data.sort(function(msgA,msgB){
       var msgACreate = new Date(msgA.createdAt),
           msgBCreate = new Date(msgB.createdAt);

       if(msgACreate > msgBCreate){
          return 1;
       } else if(msgACreate < msgBCreate){
          return -1;
       } else {
          return 0;
       }   
});
```

this assumes `data` follows the format:

```
[{
   text: "RoboChat: Johnny 5 alive!", 
   username: "RoboChat", 
   createdAt: "2014-03-19T18:52:18.533Z", 
   updatedAt: "2014-03-19T18:52:18.533Z", 
   objectId: "xnRMkxJMX3"
}, {
   text: "RoboChat: Johnny 5 alive!", 
   username: "RoboChat", 
   createdAt: "2014-03-19T18:51:28.600Z", 
   updatedAt: "2014-03-19T18:51:28.600Z", 
   objectId: "NKh7VaWY5X"
}]
```